# How would I train for a sport such as orienteering?

Tags: training

How would I train as a young semi-elite orienteer? I have some idea of the amount I should do but I do not know how I should spread it across the week. Should I group my training in the middle of the week or should I try to separate my training days?

Comment: What is the time period between events?  Do you need to train yourself in navigating or just fitness and stamina?

Comment: Welcome! Interesting question, while it is probably on topic for us, you might get better answers on [outdoors.se].

Comment: @Ste I am training just the fitness part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have some idea of the amount I should do but I do not know how I
>   should spread it across the week.

Good start. From here, set realistic goals to improve based on your idea and **don't overdo it**. Your idea may change...experiment with ideas to find your optimal training approach that is not overwhelming but challenging and progressive.

Example: If you endurance train for a 30 minutes, set a goal to endurance train for 32 minutes as your benchmark.

> Should I group my training in the middle of the week or should I try
>   to separate my training days?

By my [research](http://www.us.orienteering.org/orienteers/training/fitness), I would separate my training days.

- If you push yourself to the limit during a training session, your body needs rest to recover from it.
- Training too often increases risk of injury.